# Java - AWT - menuitem in popupmenu for system tray icon cannot show unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, menuitem, system-tray

EDIT:

I have seen another question about adding `JPopupMenu` into TrayIcon and that solves my problem.

[Adding JPopupMenu to the TrayIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667526/adding-jpopupmenu-to-the-trayicon)

---

It may be duplicate but I haven't seen it here so let me ask again:

I am with Windows 10 and Java 1.8.111. I want to make a system tray icon application in Java.

As `TrayIcon` only supports `setPopupMenu(PopupMenu)`, I can only use `MenuItem` here. Unfortunately, here I want to render some Unicode characters and they are shown as squares in the menu. `setFont()` with a `Font` which supports the content has effect, because I can see the squares grow bigger as I increase the font size, but the characters are still in square.

How can I make my characters shown?

As far as I know, this rendering problem doesn't exist for `JMentItem`. Adding support for `JPopMenu` in `TrayIcon`, thus, enabling `JMenuItem` is a known bug of `TrayIcon` and is urged for a long time, at least since Java 6.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6285881

It is OS-dependant, too, because on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, although the font is uglier, characters are shown.

Any workaround? Java FX?

Comment: One year has passed since you asked, have you found a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please see the first part; another question has the solution.